# Write even shorter visits

Tags: rascal

Is it possible to rewrite a visit like this to a single line by using a list comprehension or something similar?

```
list[str] nodeNames = [];

visit (ast) {
  case someNode(str name): {
    nodeNames += name;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can using what we call the *descendant match* operator `/`:

```
[name | /someNode(str name) := ast];
```

You see here

- a list comprehension between `[` and `]`.
- a match operator `:=` with a pattern on the left and a subject on the right.
- a descendant pattern `/someNode(str name)` that will match every subnode of the form `someNode(str name)` and will bind pattern variable `name`.

The overall effect is the same as your formulation using visit: all `name` fields from `someNode`s are collected and placed in a list. This the shortest possible solution for your problem.

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for. Thank you.